# A mathematical idea "abstract enough to be useless for physics"

Tags: ho.history-overview, reference-request

Grothendieck (if it was him) said somewhere :

> This XXX, at least, is an idea that will not be used in physics.

Q1 : Is XXX an n-groupoid? a stack?  Can someone supply the precise quote, either in French or in English?

Q2: Predecessors of this quote in the same vein would also be of interest.
Thank you.

Comment: 1. I've edited the title and the question. 2. Are you sure you aren't thinking of Hardy and number theory (factorization)?

Comment: "Very little of mathematics is useful practically, and that that little is comparatively dull. The ‘seriousness’ of a mathematical theorem lies, not in its practical consequences, which are usually negligible, but in the significance of the mathematical ideas which it connects." --GHH

Comment: "...the theory of numbers is, because of its supreme uselessness, the queen of mathematics...The great modern achievements of applied mathematics have been in relativity and quantum mechanics, and these subjects are, at present at any rate, almost as ‘useless’ as the theory of numbers...No one foresaw the applications of matrices and groups and other purely mathematical theories to modern physics, and it may be that some of the ‘highbrow’ applied mathematics will become ‘useful’ in as unexpected a way; but...it is what is commonplace and dull that counts for practical life." --GHH

Comment: XXX is "sane notation."  :)

Comment: Cam, what does "sane notation" mean? Enquiring minds want to know. Unless it's secret.

Comment: Well, Erdos used the phrase, 
   
http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1970-16.pdf   



Comment: I looked at it magnified, it was a typewriter where the letter m was extra wide and the spacing varied a bit, so "om" or "am" sometimes appear to be "an" to Google.

Comment: Cam, I am surprised you haven't thought of the XXX server (the progenitor of the arXiv), http://xxx.lanl.gov. Of course, there is also the XXX Heisenberg model, even if it's much duller (in the sense of being comparatively easy to solve) than the XXZ and XYZ models.

Comment: Dear Everyone, I honestly do not know what the phrase "sane notation" might mean, who might use it, why it is funny in this situation. I actually don't. I humbly request that someone explain this. I'm not judging anything either. I don't know what it means.

Comment: @Will, I think that Cam was suggesting that physicists' notation is intimidating and bizarre to mathematicians (as is mathematicians' to everyone else, probably).  I suspect that any deeper reading goes astray.

Comment: @Victor: the XXX in the arXiv precursor *is* the XXX of the Heisenberg model.  Paul Ginsparg initially ran the arXiv from one of the computers in his research group and indeed there were also other computers called XXZ and XYZ, IIRC.  The change of name didn't come soon enough, since URLs containing xxx were being increasingly blocked in many places :)
 

Comment: @L Spice:  Indeed!  Sorry for the confusion, Will.

Comment: Jose, Paul Ginsparg and I went to the same high school, he was a year ahead. He did not make the notable alumni list in wikipedia, maybe I can edit that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syosset_High_School as he has a separate wikipedia page. I didn't make their list either but am not notable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Ginsparg  
$$ $$
L Spice and Cam, Thanks. This was an artifact of brief communications as in a comment box. I was assuming that there was some first, very famous user of the phrase `sane notation' who was being quoted. 

Comment: The reason I used XXX ( as ???) is like x in math except that being a computer scientist I like longer and more expressive words, a rather unconcious move. I crave for the day when longer names will be an habit in math and physics. Note that it does not means I wish all single letter notation to be replaced by a longer word , but some rules for partially using long notations to alleviate the polymorphic symbol usage. This is 21th century : we have computer ( Yet I agree they so far useless to provide decent interface in writing latex).

Comment: Jérôme, I think long names cause much more harm than they do good, at least unless we can achieve the trivial task of settling on a uniform typeface convention.  For example, $G = MAN$ would surely seem bizarre to someone on the look-out for multi-character variable names.

Comment: Err, sorry, $P = MAN$.

Comment: Whatever XXX is and whoever said it, I doubt it is true.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dear Jérôme, I doubt that Grothendieck ever said that.

However, in an analogous vein, Jean Leray, a brilliant French mathematician, was taken prisoner by the Germans in 1940 and sent to Oflag XVIIA ("Offizierslager", officers' prison camp) in Edelsbach (Austria), where he remained for five years till the end of WW2.

He managed to hide from his captors that he was an expert in fluid dynamics and mechanics, lest they would force him to contribute to their war effort (submarines, planes).
Instead, he organized a course, attended by his fellow prisoners, on the foundations of Algebraic Topology, a harmless subject for applications in his eyes. It is in these courses that he introduced sheaves, cohomology of sheaves and spectral sequences.

His strategy worked out fine since these discoveries didn't play any role in the construction of weapons by the German enemy, who never cared about Leray's courses and findings. On the other hand, these theoretical tools have had a non entirely negligible role in pure mathematics since.

Comment: "a non entirely negligible role" : *quelle litote!* 

Comment: Cher Chandan, félicitations pour votre peu commune érudition: I am amazed at your command of French since I would guess that not so many native French speakers know the meaning of *litote*! (For interested readers: *litote* is a sort of understatement where you convey an idea by essentially doubly negating it.)

Comment: As "litotes", it's an English word, too.

Comment: Doug Piranha was the most feared man in the London underworld. This was largely due to his merciless use of sarcasm, dramatic irony, metaphor, bathos, puns, parody, litotes and satire. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_Brothers

Comment: The question was put to me by someone else yet when he asked it I felt I had heard it before. You might be right that It is a Hardy quote . Do you remember if it is in  his Number theory book.

A META QUESTION : ( I do not known where to ask it ? - this is a meta-meta question- ) 
How do I click the check mark to accept an answer ???? . I would be glad to give points 

Comment: @Georges : Now (lately) I found how to give point and mark the answer validation. It is a very nice parallel that should be cited more to give future scientists ways to defend themselves from soulless institutions interested in results only.

Comment: Cher Jérôme, I'm glad you liked this moving story. The quote by Hardy is to be found in his book "A Mathematician's Apology", on which there is a Wikipedia article:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Apology.

PS Je vois que nous sommes tous deux des oiseaux de nuit... Faites de beaux rêves, quand même !